# I am unable to see my image background with in the header section of my webpage when using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am creating a simple webpage and I am trying to place an image as a background within my header section. I am having some trouble with in the CSS section of my code. I believe I have used the right code, when assigning the background image, and my pathway and image name is all correct. Is there something I have done wrong?

CSS SECTION:

```
header{
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
background-image: url("images/home.png");
background-size: 100%;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 300px;
margin: 0;
padding: 20px;
position: relative;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, try setting `background-size: cover` and also make sure the path is right. If still does not work try removing the background color to check.

Comment: @khali I tried your suggestions and still no results.

Comment: The only thing I noticed is a missing closing bracket } but I don’t know if that’s something you just didn’t paste over. Your CSS is valid when tested here: https://codepen.io/2badge/pen/GRoYYGp

Comment: Can you show the folder structure of the project?

Comment: @PaulBarlow  Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue and you liked my suggestion or do I need to ameliorate my skills and suggestion?

Comment: Yes it did thankyou.

Comment: @PaulBarlow I am so happy that my suggestion worked for you and can you do me a favour by accepting and upvoting my answer, it would mean a lot to me.

Comment: @PaulBarlow  Thanks for upvoting my answer, it means a lot to me. I know you have already upvoted my answer but can you please also accecpt it because i'm just tryna grow on stack overflow and it will make my day.

Comment: @PaulBarlow Thanks for accepting and upvoting my answer you have made my day. I hope to get more chances to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct but there might an error in the **url**, check it and it will surely work.

And I have a suggestion for you next time you code instead of **%** and **px** use **Viewport Units** like **vw** and **vh** because it will help you make your webpage/website responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's working fine in my PC, but i have some suggestion which you must try if you have done already try again, because your *code is correct* and then there must be another issue.
You should check the **path of image** properly and **spellings** too and the extension of image is **.png** or something else otherwise everything is right.

And one more thing try some other css property on header section to check if it applying or not.

I hope it might work.

Comment: Thank you, tried your suggestions and still not working. Tried writing the script a different way and worked fine. Question though-could the problem be if I’m running an older version of chrome or safari?

Comment: Which script ? Are you working on SASS ? Yes there can be problem due to version issue maybe.. well it worked !